Get the parameters of a the selected task from task list
I have a list of tasks, I use WhenAll method to execute them. After execution I need the parameters I used to execute the method so I can categorize the outcome as outcome does not include those. While using foreach with list of tasks how can I access the parameters used in that task?
I know I can change my object model to include the parameters in the answer but it is a monolith that I prefer not to touch at this moment. Just wondering if there is a way to do so.
Edit some code example:
 List<Task<List<myclass>>> tasklist = new List<Task<List<myclass>>>();  



 foreach (var item in list)
 {

  tasklist.Add(_someservice.getsome(item));

 }


  var taskresults = await Task.WhenAll(tasklist);
  List<databaseclass> to_be_saved = new List<databaseclass>();

  foreach (var item in tasklist)
  {
    //this is where I initialize the database class to save objects
    //in here I want to call the parameter from individual task.

  }
                            


Could you, please, provide some relevant code?

Added some code for the context.

The array returned from Task.WhenAll contains items in the same order as the provided Tasks.
With this considered, you could use a for loop to lookup the corresponding parameter (assuming items is an indexable collection):
for (var i = 0; i < taskresults.Length; i++)
{
    var param = items[i];
    var result = taskresults[i];
}

Or if items is an arbitrary IEnumerable<T>, then you could use Enumerable.Zip:
foreach (var tuple in items.Zip(taskresults))
{
    var param = tuple.First;
    var result = tuple.Second;
}


Oh ok thanks. If they are in the same order I can just use the index then thanks.
